# Integrating the Riemann curvature tensor over a singular 2-disc

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, groupoids

There's a classic characterization of the Riemann curvature tensor.  Say, take a Riemann metric on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$.  Given a point $p \in U$ and two vectors $v,w \in T_p U$ you compute the holonomy around the boundary of the parallelogram $\{p + t_1 v + t_2 w : 0 \leq t_1 \leq a, 0 \leq t_2 \leq b\}$.  The second-order Taylor expansion of this holonomy, as a function of $a$ and $b$ (centred at $a=b=0$) is given by:

$$Id_{T_p U} + ab R_p(v,w)$$

If you think carefully about this, what it tells you is that if you have any map $D^2 \to N$ where $N$ is a Riemann manifold, you can compute the holonomy around the boundary of the disc by an appropriate "integral" on the interior of the disc, of the Riemann curvature tensor.  It's not an integral in the traditional sense, as you are performing a limit of a system of composites of functions.  But in spirit, it is reasonably-close to an integral.

Other than being a limit of a composite of a large number of functions, a  technical issue is the choice of basepoint and ensuring you are using an appropriate transport of the Riemann tensor back to one tangent space.

I imagine this observation has been written up somewhere in the literature.  Who has proven this theorem, and where might it appear?  Does this type of groupoid-y integration have a standard name?

Comment: I think this can be extracted from section 6.2 of "Gromov's almost flat manifold" by Buser and Karcher. They give an upper bound on holonomy in terms of norm of the curvature tensor and the area of the disk.

Answer (score 2):

There is ["How the curvature generates the holonomy of a connection in an arbitrary fibre bundle"](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00025-006-0228-y) by Helmut Reckziegel and Eva Wilhelmus in Results in Mathematics 46 (2006). I'm not sure that is the first place where this is proved properly, but it does do so nicely (in a more general context).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look when I'm back in my office and (hopefully) inside their paywall.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Googling the title of the paper gave me a pdf version.

Comment: Everything I find on Google is behind a paywall, unfortunately.  Anyhow, I'll head into the office today.